# Share edmx Betwen .NET projects and C# Class Library

Tags: entity-framework, entity

I had two seperated projects that used the same database, similar methods, etc.
So i've created a new solution and added those two projects.

I've created an C# Class Library project and i've writed there all the methods from the other two.
I've also created an edmx file for DAL layer. I've added the reference of the C# Class Library projects to others two but now i'm having an problem.

When i try to connect to database i get the error message: "The connection specified wasn't founded in aplication, doesn't destinate to be used with the EntityClient or isnt't valid" (i've translated this from Portuguese, so it's 100% correct).

In App.Config of C# Class Library, the connection string is:

```
 <add name="RIAEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/RIA.csdl|res://*/RIA.ssdl|res://*/RIA.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=GERAL-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=RIA;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Do i have to add a connection too in web.config of the other 2 projects that will use edmx from C# Class Library?
If yes, can someone show me an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved it by just copying the connection string of App.Config (C# Class Library) to other 2 projects.